# Excel, insert a column into a multi-cell array

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet that is a series of arrays in rows, the arrays reference individual sheets that contain information for each row like this.

```
row 1 formula =TRANSPOSE(IF(ISBLANK(A!D4:D106),"",A!D4:D106))
row 2 formula =TRANSPOSE(IF(ISBLANK(B!D4:D106),"",B!D4:D106))
```

With A and B containing the information that is being presented. I want to insert a new column but am having difficulty. If i just use the usual insert command it fails with error "you cant change part of an array". I've tried to use the solution noted [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/insert-a-column-into-an-array-formula.8359/) however this seems to only work for one row as at the final stage it fills all my rows with the values from the first.

I know two possible solutions are to either save all the formulas their first column(or delete all) and add the column in, then re-initialise the arrays, however this would take a long time; or to simply add the columns at the end, however for the layout of the array this wouldn't be ideal. So a solution that lets me insert a column at a random point in the array thats not extremely time consuming would be great if there is one.

Comment: What is your excel version? With M365 you may use dynamic array formulas.

Comment: @Harun24hr How? I can't think of a way in which you could ever manually insert a new column within the output range of a spill formula.

Comment: @Harun24hr my current version is 2304.